# "Pseudo-random" subsets of additive bases

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics, goldbach-type-problems

We say that a subset $B \subset \mathbb{N}$ is an (asymptotic) additive basis of order $k$ if the set $kB = B + \cdots + B = \mathbb{N} \setminus C$, where $C$ is a finite set of positive integers. Examples of additive bases include the squares (proved by Lagrange to be an additive basis of order 4) and in general the Waring bases, and of course the primes (recently proved by Helfgott to be an additive basis of order at most 4). Other popular examples include the polygonal numbers.

The less famous Erdos-Turan conjecture on additive bases state that additive bases cannot be "too thin", in the sense that the representation function $R_B(n)$ which denotes the number of ways that $n$ can be written as the sum of at most $k$ elements of $B$ cannot grow too slowly. In particular, Erdos conjectured that $R_B(n) > c \log n$ infinitely often for some positive constant $c$ which depends on $B$.

Additive bases where $R_B(n) = O(\log n)$ have been exhibited by Erdos in 1956 when $k = 2$ and for arbitrary $k$ by Erdos and Tetali in 1991. Van Vu showed in 2001 that one may generalize the arguments of Erdos and Tetali to the case of Waring bases and extract a thin sub-base from a Waring base. Both arguments relied on the probabilistic method, which essentially extracted a 'random' subset of integers which satisfied all the required properties with probability 1.

The problem with the probabilistic method is that while it shows existence, it is certainly not constructive. Further, it is impossible to verify if a given subset is 'random'. Thus a more concrete criterion for 'pseudo-randomness' would seem to be the critical idea.

To see the necessity of some sort of 'pseudo-randomness', take the example $B = \{3k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \cup \{1\}$. Then $B$ is an additive basis of order 3, but a rather large subset $A = \{3k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not an additive basis. One sees that $B$ is strongly biased to a linear congruence, and thus not reasonably 'pseudo-random'.

So my question is this: is there a notion of pseudo-randomness $Q$, which can be checked for a given subset of $\mathbb{N}$, such that if $B$ is an additive basis which satisfies $Q$ and $A$ is a subset of $B$ also satisfying $Q$, then $A$ is also an additive basis?

This question would be interesting in the case of primes. For instance, if both the primes and $P_2$ are 'pseudo-random' for some condition $Q$, then it would imply that the primes themselves are an additive basis of order 3.